# MiniProfiler does not load because profiler route is not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I installed `MiniProfiler.Mvc5` nuget and put in the followings:

web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

RegisterGlobalFilters:

`filters.Add(new StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc.ProfilingActionFilter());`

Global.asax.cs

```
void Application_Start()
{
    MiniProfiler.Configure(new MiniProfilerOptions
    {
        RouteBasePath = "~/profiler",
    }
    .ExcludeType("SessionFactory")
    .ExcludeMethod("Flush")
    .AddViewProfiling());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.StartNew();
}
void Application_End()
{
    MiniProfiler.Current?.Stop();
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes()
</body>\
```

rendered html:

```
<script async="async" id="mini-profiler" src="/profiler/includes.min.js?v=4.1.0+c940f0f28d" data-version="4.1.0+c940f0f28d" data-path="/profiler/" data-current-id="b0ff50dd-5d1d-4fc2-8bac-50d8f316fb03" data-ids="b0ff50dd-5d1d-4fc2-8bac-50d8f316fb03" data-position="Left" data-authorized="true" data-max-traces="15" data-toggle-shortcut="Alt+P" data-trivial-milliseconds="2.0" data-ignored-duplicate-execute-types="Open,OpenAsync,Close,CloseAsync"></script>
```

Get 404 not found on `http://localhost:64755/profiler/includes.min.js?v=4.1.0+c940f0f28d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to use Glimpse instead. It's much easier to setup. Just...

1. install Glimpse.Mvc5 nuget
2. browse to http://localhost:port/Glimpse.axd to configure the rest.
3. done

Answer (score 0):

Add this `handlers` tag in your `web.config` under `system.webServer`:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="MiniProfiler" path="profiler/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Are you using any tools that it needs to add its own handler to your config file?

Comment: Or it might be it's because of your global filters: `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);`. Did you tried without it?